# CSS auto-complete curly braces

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, curly-braces

Is it possible to add curly braces and open up the ruleset body to its own empty line automatically (autocomplete) in CSS file after pressing <kbd>{</kbd>? I can't find any info on that. I find it surprising that it doesn't exist, didn' find any answer when I google it...

VS Code does this:

```
.auto_curly_braces{}
```

And I'm looking for this: (with cursor under the selector)

```
.auto_curly_braces {

}
```

Comment: VSC does that for me so long as I set the type of the document as CSS

Comment: I think it automatically adds the closing curly brace. As for the first, how would it know if you want to open the braces or keep writing out your selector?

Comment: vs code do that:     .auto_curly_braces {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to add curly braces and open up the ruleset body to its own empty line automatically (autocomplete) in CSS file after pressing <kbd>{</kbd>?

No. VS Code will automatically add the closing curly brace, but it will not automatically create a new line for declarations inside the rulset's body.

But all you need to do to get that is to press <kbd>enter</kbd> after typing <kbd>{</kbd>.

As far as I know, it is not configurable to skip pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> to get to that text state. And it's not universally, objectively accepted as a good thing to always have each CSS declaration in its own line (especially when there's only one declaration in the ruleset), which is probably part of the reason why.